# Subscribing to WebClient Flux<DataBuffer> response for async JSON reading not working

Tags: java, jackson, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I am having issues with some custom handling of a WebClient response. I am trying to make it play nice with the asynchronous reading of JSON using Jackson.

I have verified that this works very well if I replace the source of the `Flux<DataBuffer>` with a simpler:

```
final var dataBufferFlux = DataBufferUtils.readInputStream(
  () ->  new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance, 32
);
```

But once the source of the Flux is from the webclient (as per the example test case below), it stops working. The `subscription.request(1)` becomes a no-op, leaving my `onNext` never to be called.

Any ideas?
Is the WebClient response already consumed?

Though I have managed to do some ugly testing rewrites with `Flux#blockFirst` and such where I have gotten some results back (before it crashes because I block the reactor thread), so there is content inside the Flux.

```
class StreamedParsingTest {

  @Test
  @SneakyThrows
  void testStreamedReading() {

    final var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final var parser = (NonBlockingByteBufferJsonParser) objectMapper.getFactory().createNonBlockingByteBufferParser();
    final var feeder = (ByteBufferFeeder) parser.getNonBlockingInputFeeder();
    final var allowedToRequest = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    final var subscriptionRef = new AtomicReference<Subscription>();

    final var webClient = createWebClient(Duration.ofSeconds(10), Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    wm.stubFor(
        WireMock.post(WireMock.urlPathMatching(".*")).willReturn(
            WireMock.aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody(bytes)
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ));

    final var containerMono = webClient.post()
        .uri("http://localhost:" + wm.getPort())
        .retrieve()
        .toEntityFlux(DataBuffer.class)
        .map(responseEntity -> new ContainerClass(responseEntity.getBody(), responseEntity.getStatusCode().value()));

    final var blockedValue = containerMono.flatMap(cc -> {

          cc.getDataBufferFlux()
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
              .subscribe(new Subscriber<>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                  subscriptionRef.set(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(DataBuffer dataBuffer) {
                  try {
                    if (feeder.needMoreInput()) {
                      feeder.feedInput(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer());
                      allowedToRequest.lazySet(true);
                    }
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                  feeder.endOfInput();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                  feeder.endOfInput();
                }
              });

          String foundValue = null;
          try {
            JsonToken token;
            boolean foundField = false;
            do {
              while ((token = parser.nextToken()) == JsonToken.NOT_AVAILABLE) {
                if (subscriptionRef.get() != null) {
                  if (allowedToRequest.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                    subscriptionRef.get().request(1);
                  }
                }
              }

              if (foundField && token.isScalarValue()) {
                foundValue = parser.getText();
                subscriptionRef.get().cancel();
                break;
              } else if (token == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && StringUtils.equals(parser.getText(), "Field2")) {
                foundField = true;
              }
            } while (token != null);
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException(ex));
          }

          return Mono.justOrEmpty(foundValue);
        })
        .block();

    Assertions.assertEquals("bar", blockedValue);
  }

  private static final byte[] bytes = """
      {
        "Object": {
          "Field1": "foo",
          "Field2": "bar",
          "Field3": "xyz
        }
      }
      """.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

  @RegisterExtension
  static WireMockExtension wm = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
      .options(
          WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig()
              .dynamicPort()
              .notifier(new Slf4jNotifier(true))
              .asynchronousResponseEnabled(true)
              .asynchronousResponseThreads(100)
      )
      .build();

  private static WebClient createWebClient(Duration connectTimeout, Duration readTimeout) {

    var connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
        HttpClient
            .create(ConnectionProvider.create("Test-Connection"))
            .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient
                .metrics(true)
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, (int) connectTimeout.toMillis())
                .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                    .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                )
            )
    );

    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(connector)
        .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(64))
        .build();
  }

  @Value
  private static class ContainerClass {

    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux;
    int status;
  }
}
```

*Worth noting that this uses the latest non-final version of Jackson that has support for the non-blocking ByteBuffer feeder. But if you need to run the test case, you could replace those parts with pure bytes instead.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, by going a similar but different direction.

By creating multithreaded Flux sinks I can in a manner of sorts stream the content of the Jackson JSON in a non-blocking and low-memory mode.

For the two scenarios of writing and reading JSON in a streaming way for a reactive flow, I created these two classes:

ByteBufferJsonPublisher:

```
public class ByteBufferJsonPublisher {

  private static final DataBufferFactory BUFFER_FACTORY = new NettyDataBufferFactory(
      ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT
  );

  private static final Executor PUBLISH_EXECUTOR = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(
      new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
          .setNameFormat("ByteBufferJsonPublisher-%d")
          .setDaemon(true)
          .build()
  );

  private final AtomicBoolean isSubscriptionComplete = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  public ByteBufferJsonPublisher(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
  }

  public static Flux<DataBuffer> publish(ObjectMapper objectMapper, GeneratorConsumer generatorCallback) {
    return new ByteBufferJsonPublisher(objectMapper).publishInternal(generatorCallback);
  }

  /**
   * This publishing method reuses data buffers, so you MUST NOT buffer those data buffers for later re-use. They WILL have their contents
   * changed regularly.
   */
  private Flux<DataBuffer> publishInternal(GeneratorConsumer generatorCallback) {

    return Flux.create(
        sink -> {
          sink.onCancel(() -> {
            isSubscriptionComplete.set(true);
            log.debug("Json Publishing was cancelled");
          });
          PUBLISH_EXECUTOR.execute(() -> executePublishingSync(sink, generatorCallback));
        },

        // The buffer strategy is BUFFER, so it is *technically* possible we could use too much memory here on backpressure issues.
        // But we try to take care listening to the number of requests made.
        OverflowStrategy.BUFFER
    );
  }

  private void executePublishingSync(FluxSink<DataBuffer> sink, GeneratorConsumer generatorCallback) {

    final var os = new DelegatingBlockableOutputStream(sink);

    try (os) {
      try (final var generator = objectMapper.createGenerator(os)) {
        generatorCallback.accept(generator);
      } catch (SignalCompletionException ex) {
        log.debug("Aborted publisher, since completion exception signal was thrown: %s".formatted(ex));
        sink.complete();
        return;
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        sink.error(ex);
        return;
      }

      sink.complete();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.warn("Could not create or close the delegating output stream", ex);
    }
  }

  private void ensureActiveOrThrowExceptionSignal() {
    if (isSubscriptionComplete.get()) {
      throw new SignalCompletionException();
    }
  }

  private static class SignalCompletionException extends RuntimeException {

  }

  private class DelegatingBlockableOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private final FluxSink<DataBuffer> sink;

    public DelegatingBlockableOutputStream(FluxSink<DataBuffer> sink) {
      this.sink = sink;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
      write(new byte[]{(byte) b}, 0, 1);
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) {

      DataBuffer buffer = null;
      while (len > 0) {
        ensureActiveOrThrowExceptionSignal();

        if (buffer == null) {

          // If we in a bounded demand, then we should try to wait for downstream to catch up.
          // But if we wait the max amount of time (which should be short), then move on.

          // But if none available, then we simply allocate a new one, because we have to.
          buffer = BUFFER_FACTORY.allocateBuffer(StreamingUtils.getMaxBytesInMemory()).writePosition(0);
        }

        final var writeLength = Math.min(len, buffer.writableByteCount());
        if (writeLength <= 0) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("This should never be 0 or less");
        }

        buffer.write(b, off, writeLength);
        if (buffer.writableByteCount() == 0) {

          sink.next(buffer);
          buffer = null;
        }

        // Then step forward with that amount in the current byte array.
        // There might be more left inside it to write to a next byte buffer.
        off += writeLength;
        len -= writeLength;
      }

      ensureActiveOrThrowExceptionSignal();
      if (buffer != null && buffer.writePosition() > 0) {
        sink.next(buffer);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and ByteBufferJsonConsumer:

```
public class ByteBufferJsonConsumer implements AutoCloseable {

  private final NonBlockingByteBufferJsonParser parser;

  List<String> remainingKeys;
  Map<String, Object> map;
  String picked;

  public ByteBufferJsonConsumer(JsonFactory jsonFactory, String... keys) {

    try {
      this.parser = (NonBlockingByteBufferJsonParser) jsonFactory.createNonBlockingByteBufferParser();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new CaughtRuntimeIOException("Could not create the non-blocking parser", ex);
    }

    this.remainingKeys = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(keys));
    this.map = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public void picks(String key) {
    this.picked = key;
  }

  public boolean expectsEatingWhatWasPicked() {
    return this.picked != null;
  }

  public void eats(Object value) {

    if (this.picked == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("There collector has not been marked as being at a field");
    }

    if (!this.remainingKeys.remove(this.picked)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key '%s' was never registered or was already added".formatted(this.picked));
    }

    this.map.put(this.picked, value);
    this.picked = null;
  }

  public boolean wants(String key) {
    return this.remainingKeys.contains(key);
  }

  public Object get(String key) {
    return this.map.get(key);
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
    return this.map;
  }

  public String picked() {
    return this.picked;
  }

  public boolean wantsMore() {
    return !this.remainingKeys.isEmpty();
  }

  public void starve() {
    this.remainingKeys.clear();
  }

  public NonBlockingByteBufferJsonParser getParser() {
    return parser;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception {
    this.parser.close();
  }

  /**
   * This will consume the underlying stream. If you call this method twice, you might not get the same result.
   * <p>
   * WARNING! This can currently only fetch from FIELD NAME, and does not know of nested objects! This is because the otherwise used
   * FilteringParserDelegate does not support non-blocking async filtering! So to make things easier we only get tokens and find the field
   * name and that's that.
   */
  public static Mono<Map<String, Object>> collectJsonFields(
      Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux,
      JsonFactory jsonFactory,
      String[] wants
  ) {

    return dataBufferFlux
        .scan(new ByteBufferJsonConsumer(jsonFactory, wants), ByteBufferJsonConsumer::feedBufferToJsonConsumer)
        .takeUntil(consumer -> !consumer.wantsMore())
        .last()
        .doOnEach(signal -> {

          try {
            var consumer = signal.get();
            if (consumer != null) {
              // The consumer should never be null, since on exception we just starve the consumer.
              consumer.close();
            }
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Could not close the consumer. Might resolve into a small temporary memory leak if used abundantly", ex);
          }
        })
        .flatMap(consumer -> Mono.just(consumer.getMap()));
  }

  private static ByteBufferJsonConsumer feedBufferToJsonConsumer(ByteBufferJsonConsumer consumer, DataBuffer buffer) {

    var parser = consumer.getParser();

    JsonToken token;
    try {

      if (parser.needMoreInput()) {
        parser.feedInput(buffer.asByteBuffer());
        DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
      }

      do {
        if ((token = parser.nextToken()) == JsonToken.NOT_AVAILABLE) {
          break;
        }

        pickOrEatOrSkipToken(consumer, parser);
      } while (token != null && consumer.wantsMore());

      return consumer;

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException ex) {
      log.error("Could not feed or consume the data buffer. Will starve the consumer and return what we have so far", ex);
      consumer.starve();

      return consumer;
    }
  }

  private static void pickOrEatOrSkipToken(ByteBufferJsonConsumer consumer, NonBlockingByteBufferJsonParser parser) throws IOException {

    if (consumer.expectsEatingWhatWasPicked()) {
      if (parser.currentToken().isScalarValue()) {
        consumer.eats(JsonParserUtils.getCurrentTokenValue(parser));
      } else {
        var message = "Fed consumer something it could not eat, '%s': '%s'".formatted(consumer.picked(), parser.currentToken());
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
      }
    } else if (parser.currentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && consumer.wants(parser.getText())) {
      consumer.picks(parser.getText());
    } else {

      // We do not care.
    }
  }
}
```

They work great for my situation. Fast, low-memory, can be cancalled, handles errors well, can deal pretty well with downstream request demands.